# Golang Use Slices of Interfaces for Function Argument

Tags: go

I have written a function to print a slice and would like to use it.

```
func Print_2dMat(mat [][]interface{}) {
    for index,element := range mat{
        fmt.Println(index,"=>",element)
    }
}

Print_2dMat([][]int {{1,2,3}, {1,2,3}})
```

However, I have the following error. What is the correct way to resolve it?

`Cannot use '[][]int {{1,2,3}, {1,2,3}}' (type [][]int) as type [][]interface{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **Variadic function**:

```
func Print_2dMat(mat ...interface{}) {
    for index, element := range mat {
        fmt.Println(index, "=>", element)
    }
}
```

For more details visit here: https://yourbasic.org/golang/three-dots-ellipsis/